# Has anyone managed to get the Chartjs to work in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Update: SOLVED. I was missing the script include for Chartjs in the index.html file, **Oops**:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

It works with just **Dart** following the example, but it doesn't seem to work with **AngularDart**.

I am using a fresh *Angular web application* with modifications based on the **Dart** example.

I added to *app_component.html* the same **DIV** element with one exception and that is a local-variable so I can access it via **ViewChild**:

```
<div>
  <p>Canvas</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <canvas #theCanvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

I then added the styles to *app_component.css* (plus a border to see the canvas). I can even draw to a rectangle and see it:

```
div.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
 text-align: center;
 font-style: italic;
 border: #6bc5ff 1px solid;
}
```

I then added the same chart code from the Dart example to the *app_commponent.dart* file:

```
 Angular imports...
 import 'package:chartjs/chartjs.dart';

 @Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [materialDirectives, HelloDialog],
    providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('theCanvas')
  ElementRef canvas;

  CanvasElement canvasEl;

  math.Random rnd = new math.Random();
  List<String> months = <String>[
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    canvasEl = canvas.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var data = new LinearChartData(labels: months, datasets: <ChartDataSets>[
      new ChartDataSets(
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          data: months.map((_) => rnd.nextInt(100)).toList()),
      new ChartDataSets(
          label: "My Second dataset",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
          data: months.map((_) => rnd.nextInt(100)).toList())
    ]);

    var config = new ChartConfiguration(
        type: 'line', data: data, options: new ChartOptions(responsive: true));

    Chart chart = new Chart(canvasEl, config);
  }
}
```

I added the dependency to *pubspec.yaml*:

```
chartjs:
```

Which in turn included the js dependency. As I mentioned I can make draw calls, like drawing lines, so I know the canvas works.

Dartium's console shows an error:

```
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Not a valid JS object
#0      JsNative.callConstructor (dart:js:1461)
#1      Chart.Chart (package:chartjs/chartjs.dart_js_interop_patch.dart:31:30)
#2      AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (package:DeuronNG/app_component.dart:59:23)
...
```

Does anyone know if I missed something or what the JS error means?

Comment: seems like you forgot to add chartjs native js file didn't you ?

Comment: How would I add chartjs native file? Chartjs is javascript and Chartjs.dart use the js interop to interface with it.

Comment: I updated the issue. I was missing the script include for Chartjs, Doh!

Comment: this is what I meant by native (native in JS world means pure js)

Comment: Hi @EndlessLife, you can answer your own question and then accept it. Just move the "Update: SOLVED" text to the answer slot below. That way, users of StackOverflow know that this question is answered even before clicking through (so they're more likely to click through).

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the script include for Chartjs in the index.html file, Oops:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```